# Проблема с апачем опенсервера, сайт не звпускается

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс, openserver, apache2.2

На прошлой неделе все нормально было, сейчас сайт вообще не запускается.

```html
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:27 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:27 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:27 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:27 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:28 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:28 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:28 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:28 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1p configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [notice] Server built: Jul 16 2015 11:30:50
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4092
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [notice] Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:32 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [notice] Child 4092: Child process is running
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [notice] Child 4092: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [notice] Child 4092: Starting 32 worker threads.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [notice] Child 4092: Listening on port 443.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:33 2016] [notice] Child 4092: Listening on port 80.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:49 2016] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:50 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:50 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:50 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:50 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.31 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1p configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [notice] Server built: Jul 16 2015 11:30:50
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5072
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [notice] Disabled use of AcceptEx() WinSock2 API
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:51 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `openserver' does NOT match server name!?
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [notice] Child 5072: Child process is running
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [notice] Child 5072: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [notice] Child 5072: Starting 32 worker threads.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [notice] Child 5072: Listening on port 443.
[Wed Mar 16 22:03:52 2016] [notice] Child 5072: Listening on port 80.
```

отладка mysql выдает

```html
160316 22:03:25 [Note] h:\openserver\modules\database\MySQL-5.5\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 4408 ...
160316 22:03:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160316 22:03:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160316 22:03:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
160316 22:03:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160316 22:03:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 20.0M
160316 22:03:26 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160316 22:03:26 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160316 22:03:26  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160316 22:03:27 InnoDB: 5.5.45 started; log sequence number 1595675
160316 22:03:27 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
160316 22:03:27 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
160316 22:03:27 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
160316 22:03:28 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160316 22:03:28 [Note] h:\openserver\modules\database\MySQL-5.5\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.45'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

UPD. Купила новый диск, установила опенсервер , перенесла данные  и опять выдает ошибку-"Соединение сброшено."
Логи пхп:
с чем это связано, и как исправить?

```html
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:34 Europe/Moscow] PHP   2. require() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:1
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:34 Europe/Moscow] PHP   3. CAllIBlockSection::GetMixedList() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:1405
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:34 Europe/Moscow] PHP   4. CIBlockResult->Fetch() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\classes\general\iblocksection.php:2105
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:34 Europe/Moscow] PHP   5. CDBResult->Fetch() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\classes\general\iblockresult.php:82
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:34 Europe/Moscow] PHP   6. mysql_fetch_array() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\database.php:993
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57 bytes) in E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\database.php on line 993
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP Stack trace:
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP   1. {main}() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:0
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP   2. require() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:1
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP   3. CAllIBlockSection::GetMixedList() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:1405
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP   4. CIBlockResult->Fetch() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\classes\general\iblocksection.php:2105
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP   5. CDBResult->Fetch() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\classes\general\iblockresult.php:82
[18-Mar-2016 10:04:54 Europe/Moscow] PHP   6. mysql_fetch_array() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\database.php:993
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57 bytes) in E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\database.php on line 993
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP Stack trace:
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP   1. {main}() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:0
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP   2. require() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:1
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP   3. CAllIBlockSection::GetMixedList() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\admin\iblock_list_admin.php:1405
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP   4. CIBlockResult->Fetch() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\classes\general\iblocksection.php:2105
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP   5. CDBResult->Fetch() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\iblock\classes\general\iblockresult.php:82
[18-Mar-2016 10:07:49 Europe/Moscow] PHP   6. mysql_fetch_array() E:\OpenServer\domains\un.loc\bitrix\modules\main\classes\mysql\database.php:993
```

Comment: По логам как-будто все нормально. А как выглядит "не запуск" сайта?

Comment: Долго запускается главная страница. Кеши почистил, не помогло. Белый экран.  Если остановлю сервер опенсервера- появится главная. Что-там нормально?

Comment: Долго -- это сколько?

Comment: бесконечное ожидание. Может быть, это проявилось после того, как я уронила диск. Но файлы сохранились на диске

Comment: В логах все нормально, и MySQL и Web-сервер запускаются штатно и начинаю слушать порты (MySQL 3306, Web-сервер 80 и 443). Поищите еще логи, желательно бы логи с сообщениями ошибок от PHP. Если не можете их найти, временно включите вывод ошибок PHP в php.ini - возможно будет какая-то зацепка. Пока невозможно понять, что произошло.

Comment: Решила протестировать bitrix_server_test.php.  вылезают такие ошибки http://prntscr.com/agpjwt . А на сайте вылезает "соединение сброшено". С чем это связано?